# Rest API (wordpress) being blocked on cloudflare?

Tags: rest, cloudflare

For a week now, we had issues connecting Zapier to our WordPress account as it always show the 503 error. Also, on site health, we have loopback and rest api errors. We decided to pause cloudflare for the site and it is working fine now.

My question is, is there a way to prevent cloudflare from blocking rest api?

Comment: Error 503 can be generated by Cloudflare or by the origin server, see [this documentation page](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003011431-Troubleshooting-Cloudflare-5XX-errors#503error) to help diagnosing the root cause. Can you verify in which scenario you are?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

thank you for the insight that you gave it helped me understand a bit more about the 503 error. I stumbled upon an article and the issue was similar to mine. It seems that the issue came from enabling Bot Fight Mode. Here is the article just in case some of you might encounter the same issue: https://journeybytes.com/wordpress-cron-error-503-by-cloudflare

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).